# No overload for method “ToString” takes 1 arguments in c#

Tags: c#, date

I have a data reader to read the dates from database in this format 2014-07-01.

I would like to show the dates in format July 2014.

The code is something link that:

```
<asp:Label ID="Month" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("Month").ToString("MMMM yyyy") %>'></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="Month" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Month").ToString("MMMM yyyy")) %>'></asp:Label>
```

However I encountered this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1501: 
No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments
```

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.

What am I missing ?

What's wrong with the code?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

Comment: What's the return type of `Eval`?

Comment: The .NET Framework version is Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1 on the windows server 2003.

Comment: the return type of Eval is 2014-07

Comment: 2014-07 does not look like a type to me

Comment: "Return type" does not mean "return value". What is the *type*? If it's `object` then be aware that `object.ToString()` does not have an overload that takes a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be aware of the type that Eval() returns, which is object. Type object has no ToString() with any arguments. However, DateTime does.

So cast the "Month" to a DateTime first, then call ToString() with your date-time format string:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("Month")).ToString("MMM yyyy")
```

Comment: Or, avoiding a cast: `string.Format("{0:MMM yyyy}", Eval("Month"))`